# HttpPost $params in Symfony2 LswApiCallerBundle

Tags: php, symfony, curl

I am using [this](https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswApiCallerBundle) Bundle for my request. It works for all GETs, but I am stuck with the POST params, as it requires an object and I cannot find how such an object should look like.

I make this call:

```
$response = $this->get('api_caller')->call(new HttpPost("http://de.excample.com/webcams.php",REQUESTOBJECTGOESHERE);
```

and I would like to send parameters as "utf8 = yes".

Any hint appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be an associate array:

```
$requestObject = array('utf8' => 'yes');
```

From the source code of [CurlCall](https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswApiCallerBundle/blob/master/Call/CurlCall.php) it is doing the `http_build_query` on that object. The line 281 from that `php` source is as below:

```
\$this->requestData = http_build_query(\$this->requestObject);
```

Comment: Well, that's what I got from the source as well. TBH I never tried it, I just relied in the "Expected Object, got array..." message from PHPStorm when I entered it exactly like you. It seems to work now that I test it "live", so thank you!